# Scramdisk for Linux (SD4L)

Tags: linux, encryption, truecrypt, disk-encryption

I can't find any evidence of people using [Scramdisk for Linux](http://sd4l.sourceforge.net/) anywhere. Is it a dead project, or is it just too new for people to trust its reliability and security? Have any of you used it for any length of time?

It's on SourceForge and has a GPL license. It seems to be more truly open source than TrueCrypt.

Comment: I give up.  I tried to install it from an Ubuntu .deb file, that didn't work (apparently because I have a newer version of Ubuntu).  I also downloaded the tar.gz and tried to make/install it based on their instructions, and that also failed.  

Looks like this was something developed as an academic experiment and they don't actually want people to use it.

Answer (score 0):

TrueCrypt is not really Open Source (ie not accepted by OSI) nor accepted by FSF as Free Software. But it's gratis and its source code is available, and the authors claim that is both Free and Open Source (that is wrong). Anyway most of people do not care about the strange license and just use it.
On the other hand, SD4L is kernel-dependent (depends on the version of linux kernel) and the GUI is based on Qt3 as far as I remember (and If your kernel is not suppoted by binaries, you have to install qt3 development files and compile SD4L yourself... that is much difficult). And totally it seems to be a dead project. This is probably why no much people are using it rather than TrueCrypt.

Answer (score 0):

I just built ScramDisk from source for Ubunty Natty. You need some deps:

```
sudo aptitude install linux-headers libqt4-dev libqt3-headers
```

Then

```
make
sudo make install
```

Enjoy